# Converting QByteArray to integer

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have a `QByteArray` data which when I print it out with `qDebug` it yields something like:

```
qDebug() << rawData; 
//here is the reult:
MXTP24\\x00\\x00\\xF3\\x8F
```

Now I need to convert that 4 hex string to a 32 bit integer, that is I need to parse `\x00 \x00 \xF3 \x8F` to an integer. I tried the following code but it fails:

```
QDataStream ds;
ds << rawData.mid(8,2);
ds << rawData.mid(13,2);
ds << rawData.mid(18,2);
ds << rawData.mid(23,2);

quint32 sampleCounter = 0;
ds >> sampleCounter;
qDebug() << "PARSER => onReceivePacket => sampleCounter => " << sampleCounter;
```

But no matter how hard I try it fails and prints `0`. I do not know what exactly is going on in the `QByteArray`. I think this is a trivial task but I cant figure it out

Comment: What is `rawData`? What does the data represent?

Comment: @SeanKuhlman It's just something I reveive from network socket...I just know that I need to somehow convert that 4 hex string to integer. I mean it is the QByteArray I showed in the question

Comment: Does `rawData.size()` equal 10? Try `ds << rawData.mid(6, 4);` as the only insertion to `ds`. The last four bytes look to be encoded since they can't be printed as characters.

Comment: Are you sure the data was created by a `QDataStream` on the other end?

Comment: At the very least I think you're mis-counting offsets within the `QByteArray` -- "\\" represents a single backslash character.  That is, `rawData` in the example above has 22 bytes not 26.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should not manually parse in such manner:

```
QDataStream ds;
ds << rawData.mid(8,2);
ds << rawData.mid(13,2);
ds << rawData.mid(18,2);
ds << rawData.mid(23,2);
```

This could be replaced in your case by something like this (can't test it currently, but think should work):

```
QByteArray hexEncoded = rawData.right(rawData.size() - 6); // 6 is len of "MXTP24"
```

[right()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#right) gives you trimmed (right-aligned) to the specified length byte array. And then:

```
QByteArray decoded = QByteArray::fromHex(hexEncoded);
quint32 sampleCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    sampleCounter += (quint8)decoded.at(i) << (3 - i) * 8;
}
```

[fromHex()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex) handles the hex representaion in QByteArray instead of you.
Unfortunatelly, haven't found currently the better way to convert number, cause toInt and .data() seems not working (may be cause of the 0 in beggining of 'hex' byte array)